# Finding distance Range for an Exoplanet to be detectable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, exoplanets

I have been trying to solve the following problem, I found while reading some Exoplanet detection techniques, namely, radial velocity method and Astrometry.

Problem statement:

"
Imagine yourself trying to predict presence of a planet (Earth-like) around a star(Sun-like) by either measuring it's position or velocity as a function of time. If you are able to measure changes in velocity by 1 m/s and displacement by 0.01", then find the range of orbital radius of such a planet(i.e it's distance form the star)
"
My work so far:-
Assumptions: 1. The data for velocity and displacement indicates the "precision" of my measuring devise and not the actual velocity/position shift of the star.
             2. The orbit is nearly circular.
             3. The position and velocity given are for different approaches i.e 
                radial velocity and astrometry seperately.

Since, the velocity precision is 1m/s
then the measured velocity of star about COM of star-planet system v has to be more than 1 m/s for being able to detect.
V >= 1m/s,
using reduced mass approach to Two body problem we can find 
v = (mp/ms)(Gms/r)^0.5
using the inequality above we can find an upper bound to r.
Now How do I find the lower bound? I could perhaps use the angular displacement to get the lower bound, would that be correct? 
Qualitatively, what's the issue with planet-star distance getting smaller and smaller with radial velocity method of detection?

Comment: There should be no greater lower bound than 0 (at least assuming ideal, point-like masses - a physical star of course has a surface, so you could perhaps say the star's surface or something at least suitably close so that nuance begins to creep in and the cow is no longer reasonably understood as a sphere.). Physically, as the planet gets closer to the star, it tugs _harder_, making it wobble _more_.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, as the distance getting smaller should only allow us to make better measurements, as the radial velocity of the star will become larger. What do I do with the angular displacement precision? I don't see an use of it, other than to find a separate range using Astrometric method( only this time, I will get a lower bound and perhaps no upperbound).      Am I correct so far, in assuming the problem gave me only precision and not the actual velocity, also am I going right? Thanks for your comment!.